# How to emmit the last element ussing takeWhile?

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I have stream that emits items since an element. I know which element is. Once that element is emmited the stream doesn't emit more. The problem is that it doesn't emmit the onComplete. I need something more less like [`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) but emmiting the last element too. This is the idea with marbles:

[image: Take whileish]

(Original image extracted from [ReactiveX TakeWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html))

Which operator or operators can I use to do this?

Comment: You mean this: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil(rx.functions.Func1)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I saw that operator on [its ReactiveX page](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) but as soon as I saw the two stream in the main implementation I closed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just repeating my comment:

The operator is called `takeUntil` with a `Func1<T, Boolean>` predicate parameter:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil(rx.functions.Func1)